# In CSS, how can I give two styles to same div according to its level on a <ul> list?

Tags: css, html

I am working with a nested  menu and have the same  class appear on two levels of the  tree, but I need to format said  differently in the lower level. Any ideas how I can do this? I've searched for some time and tried many different solutions to no avail. Here's my HTML and most recent attempt:

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><h3 class="toggle_action"> Meetings</h3>
    <ul class="div_toggle">
      <li><h3><a href="/index">Home</a></h3></li>
      <li><h3 class="toggle_action"> Attend</h3> // <-- same div as line 2 but needs different formatting
        <ul class="div_toggle"> etc...
```

and attempted CSS fix:

```
.toggle_action {               /// the top-level format for the div with blue text
color:#5376c5;
}
ul.topnav ul li {             /// the general <ul> formatting for the secondary level
color: #999;
}
.toggle_action ul ul li {     /// my attempt to make the div appear in gray on second level
color:#999; 
}
```

any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not compatible with all browsers but you could use the direct child selector : `.toggle_action > ul > ul > li`

Comment: You mention `div`s in your question, but your code doesn't contain any `div` elements. Are you referring to the `h3` elements instead?

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant the h3 element... edited above.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy that is helpful and good to know for future! I can't vote yet on comments but +1 in spirit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last CSS style never exists in the HTML; the `<h3 class="toggle_action">` has no children.

I think you meant this:

```
.toggle_action {             
   color:#5376c5;
}
ul.topnav ul li {            
   color: #999;
}
ul ul li .toggle_action {   
   color: #999; 
}
```

Comment: you are correct! I reversed toggle_action and ul ul li as per your suggestion and it works perfectly. Thanks!!